# Why the heck installing pop theme turned my whole ubuntu into pop os?

Tags: 20.04, themes, desktop-environments

I installed pop theme in my ubuntu 20.04. But after next system update my whole ubuntu turned into pop os.
Now how I am supposed to get my good old ubuntu back?

Comment: How did you install Pop theme?

Comment: > How did you install Pop theme? 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop   sudo apt update     sudo apt install pop-theme

Comment: This is the reason Pop OS PPA clearly instructs not to use it with Ubuntu.

Comment: >This is the reason Pop OS PPA clearly instructs not to use it with Ubuntu.   But now how I can fix this? removing the ppa is not working :(

Comment: >Does this answer your question? No not working for me

Comment: not working ? Any errors or what? If you removed the ppa, you may need to add it again before running `ppa-purge`

Comment: >not working ? Any errors or what? If you removed the ppa, you may need to add it again before running ppa-purge ️ I removed the ppa. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop` add the repo again

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1370621/1460940