# I have tried to install Pop-Desktop on Ubuntu, but now I want to turn back to default DE

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg, desktop-environments

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I've tried to download pop-desktop on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop

sudo apt update

sudo apt install pop-desktop
```

and I've got the error:

```
 dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While I was checking on the web, I've learned that this can be because of conflicting packages. Now I want to ask how to undo what I just did.

`sudo apt remove pop-desktop` didn't work and it returned with something like

```
 package pop-desktop not found
```

After all, a few things are changed in Ubuntu. E.g. Colour of the login screen is grey, the highlighting colour is light blue, and for the "Upgrade OS" settings it says "Pop!_OS version 20.10 is available".

I would like to know if doing `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` helps to fix it?
By the way, I've already done `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:system76/pop`

I'm new here. Sorry if the formatting is weird.

Comment: Installing PopOS stuff changes a lot more than just hte theme, etc.  It also overwrites the release data, etc.  The fastest way to 'restore' your system is a reinstall after you back up any data you want to keep to external media.  Installing `ubuntu-desktop` won't overwrite the `/etc/release` file or other components which made it start tracking PopOS now.

Comment: One thing is settings and neofetch still say I'm running ubuntu but idk

Comment: Did you install the window manager or the Pop OS desktop (which would replace Ubuntu) Please let me know which guide you used to help you install Pop OS. I can answer you using that information, and help you fix that problem.

Comment: Also, after you ran Pop OS, did you try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade? After you do that, if you haven't already, reboot your device and then try doing what you have already done again. Also, this stack might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308583/after-update-ubuntu-has-now-become-popos

Comment: @Jeff https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRTBlO_NWmw I used this youtube vid

Comment: @Jeff also I haven't tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245159/system-settings-wont-open-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-adding-system76-pop-ppa/1266235#1266235 that way's you can remove the ppa savely

Comment: @IdkWhatToPutAsAName Try the commands, then try removing the ppas and uninstalling PopOS with sudo apt-get remove pop-desktop

Comment: @Jeff I've decided to just reinstall and with Pop!_OS

Comment: @IdkWhatToPutAsAName That works. Do whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 3):

#### Installation/`APT` Errors.

There are two ways to fix it.

1. First, force-overwrite the files:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76_amd64.deb
   ```

   Then run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can remove the `.deb` files as you're gonna remove that package anyway:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76_amd64.deb
   ```

   Run force install:

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

#### Turning back to the default desktop environment.

Follow these steps to remove all components of Pop!_OS:

1. Add the repository again because we're gonna [`purge`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) it:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository system76/pop
   ```
2. Purge the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge system76/pop
   ```

   This will remove all conflicts/depends/packages/changes done by the PPA.
3. Remove the list files for the repository:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76*
   ```
4. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apr upgrade
   ```
5. Reboot to confirm the changes.
6. Next, remove all packages whose name starts with `pop`. Since this can be destructive if you have any packages not related to Pop! but whose name begins with the string `pop`, first run this to just print what packages will be removed:

   ```
   sudo apt --dry-run purge pop=-* system76*
   ```

   Look over the list of packages to be purged carefully and make sure they are all related to Pop!. Once you are confident that they are, go ahead and run the command:

   ```
   sudo apt purge pop-* system76*
   ```

The above will completely remove all components of Pop!_OS.

#### Restore Ubuntu

Now, let's restore Ubuntu and it's components.

1. Restore the default Ubuntu packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
   ```

   The above command is massive and will install every package which comes by default with Ubuntu. Don't worry, it won't reinstall any package, it will just install missing packages.
2. Fix any issues with package manager and clear cache:

   ```
   sudo apt clean 
   sudo apt autoclean 
   sudo apt autoremove 
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

#### Restore the default repositories.

This step is not at all necessary but is highly recommended.

1. First, confirm if the above steps were successful.

   ```
   lsb_release -a
   ```

   If it shows Ubuntu, then you can proceed. If not, then try rebooting.
2. Run this one-line copy-paste friendly command:

   ```
   sudo mkdir ~/answer && cd ~/answer/ && sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list && sudo sed -i "s/focal/$(lsb_release -c -s)/" ~/answer/sources.list && sudo mv ~/answer/sources.list /etc/apt/ && sudo rm -rf ~/answer && sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d && sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d && sudo apt update
   ```
3. Run a full upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   ```

#### You're welcome :)

If you've any questions/problems you can post a new comment/ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66387/island-of-castaway-thoughts) or [Ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Good luck :)

Comment: I did all this and I got an "Oh no something went wrong" when I logged out. I tried going to the terminal with CTRL+ALT+F3, but that didn't work. In recovery mode, I tried running all the dpkg fixes that AskUbuntu recommends and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, but nothing worked. What's going on?

Comment: I'm on 20.10. The issue ended up being with gdm3, which was pretty much broken. I installed LightDm and everything worked. When I went to go back to reinstall gdm3, thinking its files must just be broken, I got the same error. I honestly like LightDM more, so it's a non issue.

Comment: @Byte11 Pop probably installed some GDM theme as a dependency of the pop desktop. You should be able to find out what was installed by analyzing `/var/log/apt/history.log` and finding any theme or GDM related packages that were installed when you tried to install pop desktop. Personally, I prefer lightdm as well but just to let you know.

Comment: Yea, I actually just upgraded and it fixed the whole issue, so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe)

Of course you’ll have to change the path to the path in your error output.
In this case: /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76_amd64.deb

Comment: This don't fix the pop os!

Comment: @Algnis Why? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kulfy the above command is only to fix the `dpkg error (1)` above in the question. That is also not at all formatted or elaborated, whereas the OP is asking how to turn back to default DE from Pop OS! DE. So in short, this answer fixes a little issue but not all the issues.